# relcache reference is not owned by resource owner TopTransaction

Tags: postgresql, pipelinedb

I created a continunue Trasformer in pipelinedb(base on postgresql 9.5.3) to capture data that the device status code changed.
Then this CONTINUOUS TRANSFORM will call a function(trigger),
In the function, the code calculates the time range of device state changes according to the change of device state code, and writes it into a table. 
The operation in function contains select / upate / insert.
During the run, I find a lot of error messages in the database log, but these errors do not seem to affect the normal execution of the code.
However, I still worry about the bad things that will happen when I continue to receive this error in the database.

Aug 12 03:38:44 tst-gp5-srv3 pipeline[19296]: [141958-1] **ERROR:  relcache reference ct_rtd_his_narrow_func_fs is not owned by resource owner TopTransaction**
Aug 12 03:38:44 tst-gp5-srv3 pipeline[19296]: [141958-2] STATEMENT:  ct_rtd_his_narrow_func_fs

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION chr.f_modify_mn_ver_fs()
  RETURNS trigger AS
  $$
  DECLARE
      v_rowcount  int;
  BEGIN
     IF COALESCE(NEW.new_dev,'') <> COALESCE(NEW.old_dev,'') THEN
        SELECT count(1) INTO v_rowcount FROM chr.t_mn_ver_fs WHERE mn_code=NEW.mn_code AND ver_type='dev' AND is_current='Y';
        IF v_rowcount > 0 THEN
            UPDATE chr.t_mn_ver
                  SET end_time = NEW.arvl_time,
                      is_current = 'N',
                      update_time = clock_timestamp()
                  WHERE mn_code = NEW.mn_code
                  AND ver_type='dev'
                  AND is_current = 'Y';
        END IF;
```

`INSERT INTO chr.t_mn_ver_fs (mn_code, ver_type, ver, begin_time, end_time, is_current, insert_time)
                VALUES (NEW.mn_code, 'dev', NEW.new_sver, NEW.arvl_time, NULL, 'Y', clock_timestamp());
  END IF;
  IF COALESCE(NEW.new_usg,'') <> COALESCE(NEW.old_usg,'') THEN
    SELECT count(1) INTO v_rowcount FROM chr.t_mn_ver_fs WHERE mn_code=NEW.mn_code AND ver_type='usg' AND is_current='Y';
    IF v_rowcount > 0 THEN
        UPDATE chr.t_mn_ver_fs
              SET end_time = NEW.arvl_time,
                  is_current = 'N',
                  update_time = clock_timestamp()
              WHERE mn_code = NEW.mn_code
              AND ver_type='usg'
              AND is_current = 'Y';
    END IF;
    INSERT INTO chr.t_mn_ver_fs (mn_code, ver_type, ver, begin_time, end_time, is_current, insert_time)
                VALUES (NEW.mn_code, 'usg', NEW.new_usg, NEW.arvl_time, NULL, 'Y', clock_timestamp());
  END IF;
  IF COALESCE(NEW.new_sver,'') <> COALESCE(NEW.old_sver,'') THEN
      SELECT count(1) INTO v_rowcount FROM chr.t_mn_ver_fs WHERE mn_code=NEW.mn_code AND ver_type='sver' AND is_current='Y';
      IF v_rowcount > 0 THEN
        UPDATE chr.t_mn_ver_fs
              SET end_time = NEW.arvl_time,
                  is_current = 'N',
                  update_time = clock_timestamp()
              WHERE mn_code = NEW.mn_code
              AND ver_type='sver'
              AND is_current = 'Y';
      END IF;
      INSERT INTO chr.t_mn_ver_fs (mn_code, ver_type, ver, begin_time, end_time, is_current, insert_time)
                VALUES (NEW.mn_code, 'sver', NEW.new_sver, NEW.arvl_time, NULL, 'Y', clock_timestamp());
  END IF;
  IF COALESCE(NEW.new_hver,'') <> COALESCE(NEW.old_hver,'') THEN
      SELECT count(1) INTO v_rowcount FROM chr.t_mn_ver_fs WHERE mn_code=NEW.mn_code AND ver_type='hver' AND is_current='Y';
      IF v_rowcount > 0 THEN
        UPDATE chr.t_mn_ver
              SET end_time = NEW.arvl_time,
                  is_current = 'N',
                  update_time = clock_timestamp()
              WHERE mn_code = NEW.mn_code
              AND ver_type='hver'
              AND is_current = 'Y';
      END IF;
      INSERT INTO chr.t_mn_ver_fs (mn_code, ver_type, ver, begin_time, end_time, is_current, insert_time)
      VALUES (NEW.mn_code, 'hver', NEW.new_hver, NEW.arvl_time, NULL, 'Y', clock_timestamp());
END IF;
RETURN NEW;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;`

Answer (score 0):

see GitHub issue for response to this:

[https://github.com/pipelinedb/pipelinedb/issues/1947](http://github.com/pipelinedb/pipelinedb/issues/1947)